# making display tag hide

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, displaytag

two displaytags are givn.. how can i display displaytag 2 below displaytag 1 when clicked on showdetails on displaytag 1 ?? initially the displaytag 2 should be hidden.... do i have to use javascript?

displaytag 1

```
<display:table name="List" export="true" class="displaytag"   sort="list"  >
                <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />
                <display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list" value="-" ></display:setProperty>
                <display:column  property="occid" title="ID" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="firstName" title="First Name" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="lastName" title="Last Name"   ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="sonOf" title="Father's Name"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="district" title="District"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="village" title="Village"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  href="" title="Acceptance Form">
                    <a href="">Show Details</a>
                </display:column>
                <display:column  href="" title="Agreement Form">
                    <a href="">Show Details</a>
                </display:column>
            </display:table>
```

displaytag 2

```
    <display:table name="List1" export="true" class="displaytag"  id="reservationlist"  sort="list" >
                <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />

                <display:column  property="resid" title="Reservation ID" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="date" title="Date" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="weight" title="Weight"   ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="bags" title="Bags"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="amount" title="Amount"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="advance" title="Advance"  ></display:column>

            </display:table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery and call the following command:

```
$("[name=List1]").show();
```

or

```
$("#reservationlist").show();
```

**UPDATE**

If you use javascript you can do:

```
document.getElementById("reservationlist").style.display="block";
```

**UPDATE2**
To hide table you can use

```
$("#reservationlist").hide();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("reservationlist").style.display="none";
```

Comment: 1.jQuery isn't even in the tag list
2.Where is the .hide() happening in the first place

Comment: Even though jQuery is technically javascript,there is a separate tag for `jQuery`.I think your answer would've made a great comment

Comment: I can write my answer using javascript which I used much more than JQuery but I think JQuery is more popular trend and used more widely.

Comment: I never said `jQuery` wasn't trendy.All I said was that `jQuery` wasn't included in the tag list by the OP and wouldn't it be unwise to suggest him to use `jQuery` just for the sake of that one line of code

Comment: true.. makes more sense to use javascript ...as i will have to include JQuery for this... n i m using more of javascript in my project. thanks @harsha

Comment: If this answer helped you, tick this solution.